# Math increment algorithm base on index

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need math help. Says I have function that receive index from 0,4 (5 items), i have to produce and array with following value

like for index 0, the array will be [0,20] and so on..

```
index  min-max
================
0        0,20
1        20,40
2        40,60
3        60, 80
4        80, 100
```

how would the algorithm be? tried multiply and add couldn't make it.

Comment: min = i * 20, and max = (i * 20) + 20

Comment: `[Index * 20, Index * 20 + 20]`?

Comment: This Q/A site is not a platform used to solve homework  or assignments. Also no research efforts seems to have been made prior asking for the solution...

Comment: @Tom I've tried for 30 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with a simple linear step combined with a for-loop.

```js
var stop = 5, step = 20;
for (var i = 0, min = 0, max = step; i < stop; i++, min+=step, max+=step) {
  console.log(i, min, max);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you do not want to create two additional variables, you can simply multiply.

```js
var stop = 5, step = 20;
for (var i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
  console.log(i, i * step, (i + 1) * step);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you do not want a loop, you can try this:

```js
function minMaxMap(count, step) {
  return Array.from(new Array(count), (_, i) => [i * step, (i + 1) * step]);
}

var items = minMaxMap(5, 20);

items.forEach((item, index) => console.log([index].concat(item).join(', ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: What if I don't want it be a loop? Says I simply have a function that receive an index?

Comment: @GialaJefferson You can use `Array.from` as seen above.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var res = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map(function (e) { return [e * 20, e * 20 + 20]; });
console.log(res);
```

**Edit:** let **N** be a arbitrary number which defines desired array size.

```js
var N = 10;
var res = new Array(N).fill(0).map(function (e, i) { return [i * 20, i * 20 + 20]; });
console.log(res);
```

Comment: the second index of last item of array must be 100, how can we make it flexible if the item is not 5 but other value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to achieve this one, returning an array for min max.

```js
const data = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

function minMax(index) {
 return [index * 20, (index * 20) + 20]
}

const out = data.map(minMax)
console.log(out)
```